# How to display and edit summary item selected with different items with diffrent address display in dropdown list in website

Tags: asp.net-core

How to display and edit summary item selected with different items with different address display in dropdown list in website when a particular item is selected ,

if i click on three different products there address should not be same as others ,
edit button and create new list should be present as well as using nav bar in it

Comment: What function do you want to achieve and  what is your project structure ? Can you provide relevant code or provide screenshots of relevant effects? Do you want the Items of the DropdownList to be dynamically populated and changed based on different addresses? How many DropdownLists in your need?